# Count records matching criteria before a specified record

Tags: node.js, mongodb, count

I have a list of users in a collection called "queue". When a user is added to the collection the object looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectID("5543cb95a02855d404823ec3"),
  "id": "oBPLtOY2W6ChusMLAAAA",
  "added": "2015-05-01T14:53:09-04:00",
  "expiration": "",
  "word": "",
  "composed": false,
  "active": false
}
```

Now, what I am trying to do is count the number of records before a specified user in the collection. But, I only want to count the records that follow a certain criteria.

I can count the records that match the criteria like this:

```
db.collection("queue").count({
    expiration: "", 
    word: "",
    composed: false,
    active: false
}, function(err, count) {
    // Count = number of users that match the criteria
});
```

However, what I can't seem to figure out is how to count those records that only come before a specified user in the collection. The only way I can think to do it is to loop through a list of records that match the criteria, add 1 to a counter on every loop, and stop the loop when it reaches the specified user's id.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: what does "*before a specified user*" mean?

Comment: @w0lf: The records added before the specified user's `"added"` timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the `_id` value of the reference user (let's call it `reference_id`), the following should work:

```
db.collection("queue").count({
  expiration: "", 
  word: "",
  composed: false,
  active: false,
  _id: { "$lt": reference_id }
});
```

This searches earlier users based on the `_id` value. If you are searching for users with an earlier `added` value, change the query to the following:

```
db.collection("queue").count({
  expiration: "", 
  word: "",
  composed: false,
  active: false,
  added: { "$lt": reference_date }
});
```

Comment: I would like to add that it might make more sense to use the `added` field instead of `_id`. Makes the code more intuitive.